# Падежные окончания

Tags: грамотная-речь

Много *сахара* или *сахару*?  *Песка* или *песку*?

Answer (score 2):

Если "много", то можно и песку и сахару. Это так называемый родительный партитивный, обозначающий какое-то количество (обычно - часть) или меру. В современном языке рассматривается как рудимент древних форм. Фромы на -а в таких случаях столь же нормативны, но употребляются реже.

Реже проявляется в формах меры: Мешок сахару, стакан чаю, вагон лесу и неопределенного партитива: "пожарить луку", "положить сахару".

При этом равнонормативны и обычные формы на -а: мешок сахара, стакан чая, вагон леса, положить сахару.

В зависимости от самого слова частоность употребления двух форм может меняться от почти обязательного употребления партитива:  "немного луку, сахару, коньяку", до крайне редкого, несвободного: ?"кусок  льду", ?"банка вазелину", ?"кусок арбузу".

В остальных случаях вкус сахара, сорт чая и т.д. формы на -у невозможны.

Answer (score 1):

Семантика родительного падежа в данном случае указывает на количественные отношения. 
Существительные сахар, песок относятся к вещественным. Формы падежных окончаний -у (-ю) (много сахар**у**, песк**у**) возможны, но не всегда обязательны в употреблении. От основных форм они отличаются только стилистически, своим разговорно-просторечным характером.

В современном русском литературном языке родительный падеж на -а (-я) вытесняет форму на -у (-ю), распространяется и в разговорной речи.

Answer (score 0):

Где-то я читала, что если это часть вещества, а не весь сахар или песок мира, то надо говорить "сахару", "песку".